# How Can I Create a Coordinate Grid of Clickable Divs Using HTML, CSS, Javascript and If Useful JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Link to the code on JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v2n7wk9/1/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A Grid Button Example</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
div{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-2px;
    margin-right:-2px;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    position:relative;
}

.inl{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}

.top{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:auto;
}

.feature_layer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-2;
}

.unit_layer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

.first_column{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
}

.second_column{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:64px;
}

.third_column{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:128px;
}

#first_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

#second_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:64px;
}

#third_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:128px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first_row").on("click",function(){
        console.log("First row clicked.");
    });
    $("#second_row").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Second row clicked.");
    });
    $("#third_row").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Third row clicked.");
    });

    $(".first_column").on("click",function(){
        console.log("First column clicked.");
    });
    $(".second_column").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Second column clicked.");
    });
    $(".third_column").on("click",function(){
        console.log("Third column clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
Menu Below<br>
<div id="first_row" class="first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="second_row" class="first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="third_row" class="first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>

<div class="second_column" id="first_row" > <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="second_row" class="second_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="third_row" class="second_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>

<div id="first_row" class="third_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="second_row" class="third_column"> <img " src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div id="third_row" class="third_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been thoroughly stumped. I have a simple example above (not  tags, not sure they'd work, they're merely organizational, the CSS is properly loaded from a seperate .css in the actual implementation, and of course is simply inserted sans- into the CSS field on JSFiddle).

Nine divs, arranged in a simple three-by-three pattern, each an image. There are three types of IDs and three types of classes corresponding to rows and columns.

This works as expected for the first column, providing console logs (inspect the result field*) of row and column for the first column. However, only columns are noted for the two columns to the right, as if they didn't have row IDs.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this seemingly simple problem and simply can't. Help! Thanks.

*In Chrome right click on JSFiddle's Result screen (lower-right hand of the four panes) and then click on Inspect Element, along with other information the window will have a console that records console.log() calls.

Comment: You can't have duplicate ID's, it'll only use the first one, also you have a rogue double quote in one of your `img` tags

Comment: Each object has only one ID and one class, unless I'm gravely mistaken. Each class and ID definition is also unique, again unless I'm gravely mistaken. PS Thanks for catching the image tag misquote.

Comment: @user3501778 you are mistaken. Your ids are repeated.count how many times you see id="first_row" . I count three.

Comment: id's and classes do not create a composite key or anything, they are unique only to themselves. You have 3 declarations of the same ID, just use a class and you should be fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/75wt5p8f/2/ I forked your fiddle with that change

Comment: The ID and Class are, as I thought I understood it, declared in the CSS file. I thought I could apply IDs and classes to any objects I so desired, but only one each (each object could have only one class and one ID max, or one of either, or none). So every element on the page could have the same property applied to it, such as a wildcard assignment for every element on the page. I still don't understand, but I suppose I'll mark the question as solved because you can't use IDs multiple times? I have to end that with a question mark cause it confuses me so much.

Comment: you can with classes, but there should only ever be one element with a specific ID on the dom

Comment: @bruchowski You posted your working fiddle 17 seconds before mine. If you want to post yours as an answer instead of a comment, I'll delete my answer below.

Comment: Thanks so much everybody. Bruchowski that's exactly what I needed to see. I just wasn't getting it. Thank you so much. I didn't know about the multiple class syntaxt, and when I tried adding two classes to a tag it overwrote the previous for the latter. Again thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version of that JSFiddle which uses classes instead of ids for the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/4v2n7wk9/5/

Modified excerpts below.

HTML:

```
<div class="first_row first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="second_row first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="third_row first_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>

<div class="first_row second_column"  > <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="second_row second_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="third_row second_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>

<div class="first_row third_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="second_row third_column"> <img " src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
<div class="third_row third_column"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZfLsKD.gif"/> </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".first_row").on("click",function(){
    console.log("First row clicked.");
});
$(".second_row").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Second row clicked.");
});
$(".third_row").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Third row clicked.");
});
```

CSS:

```
.first_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

.second_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:64px;
}

.third_row{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:128px;
}
```